# Need help storing values and plotting in 3D matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, 3d

I am creating a matlab scrip that will later be imported into solidworks. I need help storing values from a loop equation. Below is the code. I want to create ellipses in 3D spaced d apart along the z axis with decreasing radius. How can I store the data that was input and then 3D plot that data?

```
% 1TotalMesurments

prompt={'Enter the number of measurements taken', ...
        'Enter the distance between each measurement in inches'}

name = 'Step 1 total measurements and distance';

answer = inputdlg(prompt, name);

s= str2double(answer{1}); %Number of measurement
d= str2double(answer{2}); %Distance between each measurement

% 3LoopOfCircumferenceAndWidth

for i=1:s %s is predefined in 1TotalMeasurments

    % 2Circumferenceandwidth%

    prompt = {'Enter the Circumference of 1st point', ...
              'Enter the approximate width of your arm'};

    title = 'Circumference and width of arm at first point';

    answer = inputdlg(prompt, title);

    C = str2double(answer{1}); %Circumference
    X = str2double(answer{2}); %width radius value
    Y=(((C./(2.*pi))^2).*2)-(X./2)^2; %height radius value

    plot(X,Y)

    hold on
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use either a numeric array or a cell array to store the values from inside of the loop. We first want to initialize the arrays to store your data outside of the loop, and then fill them in with each iteration through the loop. Here is a rough idea of what I'm talking about.

```
% Pre-allocate the array based on the total # of measurements
Cvalues = zeros(s, 1);
Xvalues = zeros(s, 1);
Yvalues = zeros(s, 1);

for k = 1:s 
    prompt = {'Enter the Circumference of 1st point', ...
              'Enter the approximate width of your arm'};

    title = 'Circumference and width of arm at first point';

    answer = inputdlg(prompt, title);

    C = str2double(answer{1}); %Circumference
    X = str2double(answer{2}); %width radius value
    Y = (((C./(2.*pi))^2).*2)-(X./2)^2; %height radius value

    % Assign them to your arrays for storage
    Cvalues(k) = C;
    Xvalues(k) = X;
    Yvalues(k) = Y;

    plot(X,Y)

    hold on
end
```

If `C`, `X`, and `Y` are different sizes on different iterations through the loop (doesn't look to be the case with yours), you would want to use a cell array instead of a numeric array.